# $f(a)=b,f(b)=c,f(c)=a$, find $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

> > Let $f(x)=x^2-x-2$. It is given that $a, b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
> > $$f(a)=b,f(b)=c,f(c)=a$$ Then find the value of $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}$.

My attempt:
We have:
$$\begin{array}{l}
a^{2}-a-2=b \\
b^{2}-b-2=c \\
c^{2}-c-2=a
\end{array}$$
Subtracting pair wise we get:
$$(a-b)(a+b)=a-c$$
$$(b-c)(b+c)=b-a$$
$$(c-a)(c+a)=c-b$$
Trivially $a=b=c$ satisfies. So we get $a=b=c=\sqrt{3}+1, 1-\sqrt{3}$
Thus we get
$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=\frac{3\sqrt{3}+3}{2}, \frac{-3-3\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
Now if $a\ne b \ne c$
Then we have:
$$(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)=-1$$

Letting $p=a+b+c$ we have
$$(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)=-1$$ $\implies$
$$p(ab+bc+ca)-abc+1=0$$

Any hint here?

Comment: I would try solving $f\circ f\circ f(a)=a$, though granted its likely to be a monster degree $8$ polynomial to solve.  Potentially $4$ different values for $\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c$ though, so not sure what "**the value**" referred to would mean.

Comment: Notice that $f(f(f(a)))=a,f(f(f(b)))=b,f(f(f(c)))=c$

Comment: Does the question ask for the sum of all possible such values ? That's considerably easier using Vieta.

Comment: Not really, but can you help with sum of all such possible values too?

Comment: @EkaveeraGouribhatla Some context would help here. Is there an expectation that there is a solution lighter than brute force? $(f\circ f\circ f)(x) -x$ happens to factor, but it's not the friendliest calculation to carry out by hand.

Comment: @dxiv Eww... it has 4 solutions, two fixed points $a=b=c$ (found by OP) and two groups of three solutions. Reaching the limits of Wolfram Alpha, need to fire full Mathematica to calculate $1/a+1/b+1/c$

Comment: @Momo I believe it can be shown (with a little work) that each group is the set of roots of one of the cubic [factors](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+z%5E8+-+4+z%5E7+-+4+z%5E6+%2B+26+z%5E5+%2B+3+z%5E4+-+54+z%5E3+-+3+z%5E2+%2B+34+z+%2B+10), then the respective sums follow by Vieta.

Comment: @dxiv the other two values are $\frac{3}{5}$ and $-3$ so there must be a nicer way. I've thought about the cubic factors as well, it looks they are the quotient of the first two coefficients not of your $P(z)$, but $P(1/z)$. Too lazy to think :)

Comment: @Momo FWIW, WolframAlpha can solve for $\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c$; see the ["substitution"](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%5E2-a-2%3Db%2C+b%5E2-b-2%3Dc%2C+c%5E2-c-2%3Da%2C+1%2Fa%2B1%2Fb%2B1%2Fc) result.

Comment: An alternate way to avoid factoring a 6-degree polynomial  would be to find possible cubics $p(x)$ s.t. $p(x) \mid  p(f(x))$, however no easy way to find that comes to mind.

Comment: @Momo Doing the calculations by hand makes it pretty obvious that the coefficients were "arranged" so as to get a nice result in the end. I guess someone better versed in [periodic points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_points_of_complex_quadratic_mappings#Cycles_for_period_greater_than_2) of quadratic maps could tell more about cases like this.

Answer (score 4):

From the condition, we need $f\circ f\circ f(a)=a$.  Now
$$f(x) = x^2-x-2=(x-2)(x+1)$$
$$f\circ f(x) = (x^2-x-4)(x^2-x-1)=x^4-2x^3-4x^2+5x+4$$
$$\implies f\circ f\circ f(x)=(x^4-2x^3-4x^2+4x+2)(x^4-2x^3-4x^2+4x+5)$$
$$\implies f\circ f\circ f(a)-a=a^8-4a^7-4a^6+26a^5+3a^4-54a^3-3a^2+34a+10 \\=(a^2-2a-2)(a^3-3a-1)(a^3-2a^2-3a+5)$$

It is easy to note all roots are real (using Descartes and evaluation at $a=-1, 0, 1$), so we have $8$ possibilities for $a$, which fall into two cases.

Case 1: The first/quadratic factor gives $a=1\pm\sqrt3$, each of which is also a solution to $f(a)=a$, so as you have already noted, we have two values for $\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c=\frac3a$ from these, viz. $\frac12(\pm3\sqrt3-3)$.

Case 2:  Now we have no more roots of $f(a)=a$, hence the rest of the roots (six roots from the two cubic factors), must contribute to two possible sets of $\{a, b, c\}$.

Taking the first cubic factor,
$\alpha^3-3\alpha-1=0 \implies f(\alpha)^3-3f(\alpha)-1 = (\alpha^2-\alpha-2)^3-3(\alpha^2-\alpha-2)-1 \\=(\alpha^3-3\alpha-1)(\alpha^3-3\alpha^2+3)=0$

i.e. if $\alpha$ is a root of the first cubic, so is $f(\alpha)$.  Thus the roots of that cubic contribute one set of $\{a, b, c\}$.  Now using Vieta, sum of the reciprocal of roots is $$\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c=\frac{ab+bc+ca}{abc}=-3$$

Similarly the roots of the last cubic form the last set of possible $a, b, c$, hence have a sum or reciprocals $=\frac35$.

Summarising the value of $\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c \in \{\frac12(\pm3\sqrt3-3), -3, \frac35\}$, four possibilities.

Comment: P.S. The terrible step for calculation is the factorisation - even though the quadratic factor is easy to get from $f(a)=a$ satisfying the same polynomial, and the rest ought to be two cubics.

Answer (score 3):

The following uses the symmetry of the problem and "lucky" cancellations of terms to get the result with somewhat less brute work.

The case $a=b=c$ is obvious and will be left out.

Otherwise, with $u=a+b+c, v=ab+bc+ca, w=abc$, the OP showed that:

$$
uv - w + 1 = 0 \tag{1}
$$

A second relation can be derived by summing the three equalities $a^2-a-2-b=0$ and using the Newton identity $a^2+b^2+c^2=u^2-2v\,$:

$$
0 = u^2 - 2u - 2v - 6 \tag{2}
$$

Then, multiplying $a^2-a-2-b=0$ by $a$ and eliminating the $a^2=a+2+b$ term gives:

$$
\begin{align}
0 &= a^3 - a^2 - 2a - ab
\\ &= a^3 - (a + 2 + b) - 2 a - a b
\\ &= a^3 - 3a - b - a b - 2 \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

Summing the three equalities and using another Newton identity $a^3+b^3+c^3=u^3 - 3uv + 3 w$:

$$
\begin{align}
0 &= (u^3-3uv+3w) - 4 u - v - 6
\\ &=  u^3 - 4 u - v - 3 uv + 3 w - 6\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$

At this point $(1),(2),(4)$ are three equations that can be resolved for $u,v,w$.

Substituting $uv = w - 1$ from $(1)$ into $(4)$:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
0 &= u^3 - 4 u - v - 3 (\cancel{w} - 1) + \cancel{3 w} - 6
\\ &= u^3 - 4u - v - 3\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$

Eliminating $v$ between $(2)$ and $(5)$ by subtracting $2 \times (5)-(2)\,$:

$$
\begin{align}
0 &= 2 u^3 - 8 u - \bcancel{2 v} - \cancel{6} - (u^2 - 2u - \bcancel{2v} - \cancel{6})
\\ &= 2 u^3 - u^2 - 6 u
\\ &= u(2u+3)(u-2)\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$

For each $u \in \{-\frac{3}{2}, 0, 2\}$, the other variables $v,w$ follow from $(2)$ then $(4)$:

$$
(u,v,w) \in \left\{\; \left(-\frac{3}{2}, -\frac{3}{8}, \frac{25}{16}\right), \left(0, -3, 1\right), \left(2, -3, -5\right) \;\right\}
$$

The first triplet corresponds to the cubic $16 z^3 + 24 z^2 - 6 z - 25$ which has two complex conjugate non-real roots, but the other two triplets qualify, so in the end $\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}= \dfrac{v}{w} \in \left\{ -3, \dfrac{3}{5}\right\}\,$ (again, not counting the two cases where $a=b=c$ are all equal to either root of the original quadratic).

---

[ *EDIT* ]   The steps above are not reversible, so the possibility exists that extraneous solutions were introduced along the way. Therefore the two solutions $(u,v,w) \in \{ \left(0, -3, 1\right), \left(2, -3, -5\right) \}$ still need to be verified to work, as was done towards the end of [@Macavity](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/58320/macavity)'s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4145918/291201) for the same two cubics, where both sets of roots turned out to be eligible solutions.

Comment: Nice use of symmetric polynomials! +1

Comment: @Macavity Thanks, and you had my +1 already for making it look less painful than it first seemed. FWIW I am pretty sure (though not so keen to actually check ;-)) that the "bonus" cancellation of $w$ terms in $(5)$ is what also makes your sextic factor into the two cubics.

Comment: I am in fact curious to understand where the non-real solutions in your working disappeared in the polynomial I had - don't seem to have ruled out any complex solution in my post. Shouldn't be an artefact specific to the $u, v, w$ space.  Will check.

Comment: @Macavity Good point, which I think the latest edit should cover.